# Why does this binary search code give wrong output on Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, binary-search

Why does this binary search code give wrong output on Eclipse IDE but gets accepted when submitted to Coursera? This is a sample input for which it shows the wrong output.

Sample Input:
5 3 2 4 1 5
3 1 2 7

Output:
-1 -1 -1

Clearly, the element '1' is present is the input array. But the output for that is -1 instead of 3.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BinarySearch {

    static int binarySearch(int[] a,int l,int r,int x) {
        //write your code here
    if(l<=r){
    int mid =l + (r - l)/2;
    if(x==a[mid])
        return mid;
    else if(x<a[mid]){
        return binarySearch(a,l,mid-1,x);
    }
    else
        return binarySearch(a,mid+1,r,x);
    }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FastScanner scanner = new FastScanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] b = new int[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
          b[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            //replace with the call to binarySearch when implemented
            System.out.print(binarySearch(a,0,n-1,b[i]) + " ");
        }
    }
    static class FastScanner {
        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;

        FastScanner(InputStream stream) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String next() {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Btw. I run your code with input you provided in some online IDE, I got `-1 -1 -1` on output, which is different from `-1 1 -1` you've got.

Comment: @Amongalen You are right. I changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is with your input data and not the code itself. If you search information about binary search you can find: "binary search is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a **sorted** array". Your input isn't sorted.

You would have to sort the array before running the search which would be a bad idea - searching with other algorithm would take less time than sorting.

If you try to input sorted data, eg.:

```
5 1 2 3 4 5 
3 1 2 7
```

The result will be `0 1 -1` - just as expected.